# How to find the modulus of the tension of a wire when a sphere is over a bar?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is as follows:

> The figure from below shows a system which is at equilibrium. The
>   sphere is frictionless, homogeneous and its mass is $5\,kg$. The
>   homogeneous bar has a mass of $10\,kg$. Find the modulus of the
>   tension of the wire. Assume that the acceleration due gravity is $10$
>   meters per second square. M is the midpoint of the bar.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&62N\\
2.&71.25N\\
3.&80.05N\\
4.&92.25N\\
5.&100N\\
\end{array}$

Can someone help me here?. I'm not exactly how to apply the condition of equlibrium for this problem. I'm confused exactly how should I use the information of the angle given at one end of the wire.

What I've attempted to do was the following:

$-Tl+100\sin 53^{\circ}\left(\frac{l}{2}\right)+50\sin 53^{\circ}\left(\frac{l}{2}\right)=0$

But this did not solved the problem. The part where I'm strugglin the most is where are the forces acting. Therefore I need help with the **free body diagram of the forces here**. Can someone help me here please?.

Answer (score 1):

Let the sphere exert a force $F$ on the rod perpendicular to it. We know that the vertical component of this force will be we equal to the weight of the sphere. $$F\times\cos37^o=10\times 9.8$$ 
Now, let the component of the weight of the rod in perpendicular direction be equal to $F'$.
$$F'=5\times 9.8\times\cos37^o$$
We know that the system is in equilibrium. This implies that $\tau_{net}=0$ on the rod. This gives us our final equation which gives the value of tension $T$.
$$\frac {F+F'}2=T$$